# How to downlad/fetch data in background at specific time?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, fetch, nsurlsession

I would like to my app has a possibility to conect in the background with the serwer and download/fetch new data (articles in this case) using .php script at 9:00 am each day. I am looking for some tutorials about it or maybe you have some solutions for me, which could help me in it?

Comment: There isn't any sort of scheduler in IOS that anybody has access too; so hoping that your app will run itself at 9am is a mission impossible I fear.

Comment: Ok, in this case how to fetch data in bacground in genereal? Dou you know some tutorial about it?

Comment: When you background fetch you mean download data while your app is running or download data even if your app isn't running. I ask cause again the latter is mission impossible.

Comment: I mean fetch data from the server side when application is running in the background. Something like in message app. When you receive a new message you have an information about it. Here I would like to receive a notification, when new article is on the server.

Comment: You can surely do this with notifications and CloudKit subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a silent push notification to wake up your app.
That can be done adding this in your payload:

```
   aps: { 
      content-available: 1 
   }
```

Also, you need to enable background fetch in your project capabilities, just
check `Background fetch` checkbox in `Project Capabilities -> Background` Modes

[Project Capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3C27.png)